# Error Code: 1052. Column 'seq_no' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, mariadb

I want to bring the `nickname` of '`TB_MEMBER_INFO`'. So I used the command below.

```
SELECT
        seq_no,purchase_means,value,gbrick_wallet_address,status,reg_date,permission_date,nick_name
        FROM TB_PAYMENT_INFO
        JOIN TB_MEMBER_INFO
        ON TB_PAYMENT_INFO.member_seq = TB_MEMBER_INFO.seq_no
```

But it caused me an error.

> Error Code: 1052. Column 'seq_no' in field list is ambiguous

What's the problem?

I need your solution.

Comment: *Always* qualify your column names (with the table alias) and you will *never* have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like TB_PAYMENT_INFO table also has a column seq_no, which causes the error. Just modify the query to

```
 SELECT
    TB_MEMBER_INFO.seq_no,purchase_means,value,gbrick_wallet_address,status,reg_date,permission_date,nick_name
    FROM TB_PAYMENT_INFO
    LEFT JOIN TB_MEMBER_INFO
    ON TB_PAYMENT_INFO.member_seq = TB_MEMBER_INFO.seq_no
```

and that should work.

Comment: You should also qualify each of the other columns for clarity.